# диалог с chatgpt из ide консоли

Tags: python, requests

Не получается вести диалог с chatgpt из под ide консоли. Выдаёт ошибку 401

```
def send_message(api_url, api_token, message):
    headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer _тут api токен_" + api_token }

    data = {
    "text": message}

    # Make a request to the API with the message and API token as parameters
    response = requests.post(api_url, headers=headers, json=data)

    # Check the response from the API
    if response.status_code == 200:

    # If the request is successful, print the response text
    print(response.json()["text"])
    
    else:
       
    # If the request is unsuccessful, print an error message
    print("Failed to send message. Error code: " + 
    str(response.status_code))
 
    if 
    __name__ == "__main__":
    model_name = "text-davinci-003"
    api_url = f"https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/{model_name}/chat"
    api_token = "тут api токен"
    message = input("Enter a message to send: ")
    
    # Call the send_message function to send the message
    send_message(api_url, api_token, message)
```

Comment: Спросите у бота - он подскажет.

Comment: `"Bearer _тут api токен_"` - у вас в программе прямо так и написано?

Comment: Отступы выставьте в коде как полагается.

Comment: "Bearer _тут api токен_" - это писал непосредственно Я,  для того чтобы отметить что там должен стоять апи токен

Comment: `"Bearer _тут api токен_" + api_token` - вы к строке с токеном еще раз прикрепляете токен из переменной? По идее должно быть `"Bearer " + api_token`

Comment: Вставьте код как есть, потом выделите и нажмите кнопку `{}` над редактором вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь с правкой

Comment: @developaiham ну все равно проблемы с отступами остались - `if __name__ == "__main__":` почему-то внутри функции, и отступа после него нет. После if и else также отступов нет.

Comment: @insolor Если  "Bearer__ (указания без токена) "  оставить то выдает ошибку 401

Comment: @developaiham `"Authorization": "Bearer _тут api токен_" + api_token` тут у вас внутри строки `"Bearer _тут api токен_"` уже есть токен, а потом вы еще справа делаете `+ api_token`, т.е. добавляете токен еще раз. Либо у вас токен из двух частей, либо api_token - пустая строка?

Comment: @insolor Нет один, перезаписал как: ""Authorization": "Bearer _тут api токен_" удалил остальное в строке 
ошибка 403

Comment: Зачем закрывать вопрос, если проблема не решилась?

Comment: @insolor Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Строка с токеном должна выглядеть так: `"Bearer {api_key}"`. В переменной `api_key` хранится токен.

Вот немного другой рабочий вариант кода:

```
import requests

# API
url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/text-davinci-003/completions"

# API(токен)
api_key = "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"


prompt = "Привет бот!"

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {api_key}"
}

# API request data
data = {
    "prompt": prompt,
    "temperature": 0.5,
    "max_tokens": 1024,
    "n": 1,
    "stop": None,
}

# Отправляем запрос
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.json()["choices"][0]["text"])
else:
    print(f"Error: {response.text}")
```

Comment: Вы свой токен в ответе выложили?

Comment: @insolor нет, там рандомный токен

Comment: @gfd2 Спасибо у вас рабочая программа, исправил по вашему замечанию:
 "Bearer {api_key}"    все равно выдает 401

Comment: @developaiham `"Bearer {api_key}"` или `f"Bearer {api_key}"`? Между этими двумя вариантами очень большая разница.

Comment: @insolor "Bearer {api_key}" вот так, эта ошибка исправлена, выдает ошибку на print(response.json()["text"])

Comment: @gfd2 при некоторых изменениях в вашем коде удалось вести полноценную переписку с ботом, спасибо